# Allow me to connect positions in my timeline to existing teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

When I add a position to my developer timeline, I am prompted to create a team for the position:

[image]

The team (Autodesk) in this case [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/3/autodesk) but there does not appear to be a way to link my position to the existing team.

Please provide a way to link positions to existing teams.

Comment: If you edit the position, are you able to link to the team?

Comment: @bluefeet No, unless perhaps the "Company/team" text box is supposed to give me some kind of autocomplete option to do so? https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy0ft1v1vauayxa/Screenshot%202016-03-30%2013.48.41.png?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, what if you type in the Autodesk again when editing?  I agree it isn't intuitive, just trying to see if they will link at this moment.

Comment: @bluefeet Editing the position, retyping "Autodesk" and saving it brought back up the "Create new team?" prompt along the bottom of the post. I clicked "not now", and now the prompt is gone and does not appear if I edit/retype "Autodesk"/save again.

Comment: Weird, I'm sure that's not intended.

Comment: Is it possible you missed a suggestion to join that team when you FIRST added the role (or that you imported it)?  I ask because the problem of proposing a dupe team *after* creation - like in your screenshot - is known, but I *think* when you first enter a company, it usually suggests a team if one exists.

Comment: @Jaydles I'm not sure where/how that prompt would have appeared. I haven't imported anything, but here is [the creation step](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6crpdj6oyvjr5uj/Screenshot%202016-03-30%2014.08.15.png?dl=0), no prompt has appeared. I've [just clicked "save"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/azopo9a4oz3bnu0/Screenshot%202016-03-30%2014.09.06.png?dl=0) and the only prompt is the "Create new team" prompt. Clicking continue [definitely goes to "Create new team"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gg406v19kksy7d/Screenshot%202016-03-30%2014.09.29.png?dl=0), there is no option to use an existing one.

Comment: @Jaydles I also just found the "import" link, and imported everything, causing a bunch of duplicates. The newly imported item still doesn't provide any option to link to the existing Autodesk team.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you should get this dropdown when editing the team name.

[image: team auto-complete]

We also have a "request to join" feature in teams, that wasn't enabled on production. After that you should start seeing this on your item after you edit (you still have to pick it in the auto-completion when editing first):

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting that drop-down. I really wasn't before, despite typing really slowly and waiting for one to appear.