# Matching existing teams on import

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

As in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320078/allow-me-to-connect-positions-in-my-timeline-to-existing-teams) when you add a new position to your developer story you can pick a team as the organisation.

However after importing from the old careers CV it doesn't make the connection. I get

[image: Would you like to create a team page for Softwire? Continue, Not now]

even though there's already a [team page for Softwire](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/13/softwire), and [I'm already a member](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/13/softwire?tab=members). In that case worth auto-matching me to the team, and / or giving me the option to pick from existing team(s) with the same name I'm a member of, or if none any matching that I'm not a member of? Or at least some text to stop me accidentally creating a duplicate team.

I realise this is a minor nit (sorry!) and may only be relevant whilst people migrate from CV to Developer Story, but there used to be other import mechanisms e.g. from LinkedIn this could apply to as well. (Unless we can then attach LinkedIn organisation IDs to teams, etc.)